# How to setup default date for jQuery inline datePicker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using this [jQuery inline datePicker](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/inlineDatePicker.html) plugin sample but I don't know how to set up default date selected.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('.date-pick').datePicker({
    defaultDate: $.datepicker.parseDate("d m y", "31 8 2009")
})
```

Comment: It also seems to accept simple strings and interpret them intelligently. For example, this sets the default date to 2 months in the past: `... defaultDate: "-2m" ...` however, it doesn't seem to actually *select* the date. It just makes sure to display that date's month when the calendar popup appears.

Comment: That isn't a solution for the date picker linked to. That is a solution for the jQuery UI date picker...

Comment: This must be out of date now, because when I test it I get `Object has no method 'datePicker'`, it is `datepicker` now I think.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use the `dpSetSelected` method . I've added that into the code from the example page below:

```
$(function()
{
    $('.turn-me-into-datepicker')
        .datePicker({inline:true})
        .dpSetSelected('01/04/2010') // The string should be in Date.format
        .bind(
            'dateSelected',
            function(e, selectedDate, $td)
            {
                console.log('You selected ' + selectedDate);
            }
        );
});
```

As mentioned, if you have [changed Date.format](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDateFormat.html) then you will need to ensure that the string is in the format you changed it to.

Comment: This is the correct answer; everyone please upvote it, and down-vote the answers for jquery's default datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Here: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDefaultToday.html

```
$(function() {
     var date = new Date(); // replace with your date
     $('.date-pick').datePicker().val(date.asString()).trigger('change');
});
```

#### OR

Set date in your field:

```
<input class="date-pick" type="text" value="1/1/2009" />
```

Comment: this is possible when the datepicker is linked to a input, but my inline datepicker is linked to a div.
:( I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: ok, than use the first approach with .val('1/1/2009').trigger('change');

Comment: you cannot assign a value attribute to a div tab!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply set value of that input box like
$('#date-picker').val('22 Jun 2015');

Answer (score 0):

```
$("selector").datepicker('setDate', 'today');
```

To set UI widget and 'input' element.